# Not able to install curl-devel package on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos-7, linux-kernel

I run CentOS 7.3 as production server. I executed following commands in sequence ... But not able to install the curl-devel package.

```
$ yum clean all
$ yum update
$ yum install curl-devel

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No package curl-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Got the above output. Not able to install. The same thing happens when I'm trying to install libxml2-devl and openssl-devel. So how can I install above packages?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean [libcurl-devel](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libcurl-devel-7.29.0-46.el7.i686.rpm.html)? I found listings for libcurl-devel, libxml2-devel and openssl-devel on [pkgs.org](https://centos.pkgs.org/), all maintained in the official CentOS repository.  Do you get an error trying to install using those names?